# symfony Doctrine migration adding boolean column and field length

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a symfony 1.4 project and I am adding a new column via a migration. The new column in `schema.yml` looks like this:

```
has_private_data: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: false }
```

The migration that gets generated looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 */
class Version26 extends Doctrine_Migration_Base
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->addColumn('device', 'has_private_data', 'boolean', '25', array(
             'notnull' => '1',
             'default' => '0',
             ));
        $this->addColumn('device_history', 'has_private_data', 'boolean', '25', array(
             'notnull' => '1',
             'default' => '0',
             ));
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->removeColumn('device', 'has_private_data');
        $this->removeColumn('device_history', 'has_private_data');
    }
}
```

Why it the length of this boolean field being set to `25`? (My backend database is MySql.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be save by ignoring that. In doctines `Table.php` on line 1361 you can find that if the type is booelan the `length` will be fixed to `1`.

```
            case 'boolean':
                $length = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if the behavior I was seeing is a bug in Doctrine or something expected?